# How do I write a log function that intersects the axis at particular points?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I'm trying to write a log function that intersects both the x and y axis at 100.

Through *trial and error* I have come up with this function, which is close to what I want. It appears to intersect the x axis at 99, and the y axis at 100.

[$y=-50\log(x+B)+C$](http://fooplot.com/index.php?&type0=0&type1=0&type2=0&type3=0&type4=0&y0=&y1=50%2a-log%28x%2b1%29%2b100&y2=&y3=&y4=&r0=&r1=&r2=&r3=&r4=&px0=&px1=&px2=&px3=&px4=&py0=&py1=&py2=&py3=&py4=&smin0=0&smin1=0&smin2=0&smin3=0&smin4=0&smax0=2pi&smax1=2pi&smax2=2pi&smax3=2pi&smax4=2pi&thetamin0=0&thetamin1=0&thetamin2=0&thetamin3=0&thetamin4=0&thetamax0=2pi&thetamax1=2pi&thetamax2=2pi&thetamax3=2pi&thetamax4=2pi&ipw=0&ixmin=-5&ixmax=5&iymin=-3&iymax=3&igx=10&igy=10&igl=1&igs=0&iax=1&ila=1&xmin=-49.72300324443931&xmax=178.4114177292655&ymin=-75.02626739926626&ymax=127.75631262770665)

I notice that for a function like:

$y=A\log(x+B)+C$

- A controls the slope
- B shifts horizontally
- C shifts vertically

I'd like to learn how to write a log function like this such that the intersections of the axis are whatever arbitrary points I choose.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by $A^*-\log(x+B)+C$ - it's the $^*-$ that puzzles me. I'll assume you just mean $y=A\log(x+B)+C$.

So say you want the graph to intersect the $x$-axis at $r$ and the $y$-axis at $s$. That means you want $s=A\log B+C$ and $0=A\log(r+B)+C$. That's two equations in three unknowns, so there will be lots of solutions. You could even insist on, say, $B=1$. Then the 1st equation tells you $C=s$, and the second becomes $0=A\log(r+1)+s$, which says $A=-s/\log(r+1)$. So as long as $r\ge-1$ one answer to your problem is $y=-{s\over\log(r+1)}\log(x+1)+s$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. My first post here so I have a bit to learn about notation and formatting. I have amended my post. Great answer :)